# JdbcTemplate - queryForList - running slow for large volume of data

Tags: jdbctemplate

I am using Spring Boot + CommonsDBCP + JdbcTemplate. I need to fetch records from Hive Table which has a large volume of data.

SQL:  `select * from customer`

Total Records: 52K.

I am using **List<Map<String,Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL)** to fetch the records. This runs slow for the above-mentioned number of records.

This uses **RowMapperResultSetExtractor** which takes **96 seconds** to extract data. If the data volume increases, the query time will increase.

Any suggestion to improve this time or any other methods in jdbctemplate to use?

Answer (score 1):

You could once do a normal JDBC with try-with-resources, using `SELECT a, b, c, ...` or use the ResultSetMetaData giving column-label-to-column-no. A List of Map is expensive, So a List of Objects would be better. There are many RowSet classes.

Last but not least simply *not* collecting a List, but iterating through all would be ideal.

One feature when local memory slows things down, is to use `Statement#setMaxRows` or `setLargeMaxRows` to use parts.

There is still one other alternative: a table dump.

Possibly also a transactionless query may help.

*These are all debatable measures; one has to try out. A convincing improvement that I could reuse everywhere I never found. Start with other answers first.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class that can be mapped to your `customers` table you could try writing a custom `RowMapper` that maps your entries in the table to a `List` of the relevant class:

```java
List<Customer> customers = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM customers", getRowMapper());//where getRowMapper` is a method that returns a relevant RowMapper
```

Another alternative is:

```java
List<Customer> customers = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM customers", Customer.class);
```

But this latter solution will also make use `RowMapperResultSetExtractor` and I believe will still process results slowly.

I do remember reading something somewhere in the Spring JDBC javadocs that *not* using a custom `RowMapper` is inefficient because the relevant that class that does the mapping needs to compare the results with the relevant class to ensure columns are matched to the relevant attributes, which takes time.

Comment: there are no classes to map. yes, it takes time to map the attributes. In this particular scenario, there are 57 columns and 52K rows. It takes time to process these columns  (**ColumnMapRowMapper**) and rows (**RowMapperResultSetExtractor**) one by one.

Comment: @saravanan you may want to consider creating a class that maps your results and see if it improves efficiency if it is a major concern.